# Can a GitHub pull request be created directly from TortoiseGit?

Tags: github, tortoisegit

Currently, I'm having to browse to github.com to create a pull request for a given feature branch that I previously pushed using TortoiseGit. It would be really nice to be able to do this directly from the comfort of Windows Explorer using TortoiseGit. Is this currently possible or would this require some GitHub integration work from the TortoiseGit team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature present in TortoiseGit as of version 2.12.

After a push, GitHub displays a link in the Git progress dialog which can be clicked on directly to create a a pull request using a browser:

[image]